# Adapter not attach skipping layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

**I am getting an error saying no adapter attach skipping layout.and the list doesn't appear in when emulator runs.please help.I cant see anything in list.screen appears blank.other items in the activity are appearing.i have seen almost all answer on the internet but didn't get any solution .and also when i tried to make a listview in other tab i got the list.**

this is **songsTab Activity**

```
public class SongsTab extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<songInfo> songs = new ArrayList<songInfo>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    songAdapter songAdapter1;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Cursor cursor;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v. findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        songAdapter1 = new songAdapter(songs, getActivity());
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
                linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(songAdapter1);
        solved();
        checkUserPermission();

        Thread t = new runThread();
        t.start();
        return v;
    }

    public void solved() {

        songAdapter1.setOnitemClickListener(new songAdapter.OnitemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemclick(songAdapter.ViewHolder holder, View v, final songInfo obj, int position) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;

                } else {

                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(obj.getSongPath());
                                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                        mp.start();
                                        seekBar.setProgress(0);
                                        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                                        Log.d("Prog", "run: " + mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                                    }
                                });


                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }
                        }

                    };
                    myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

                }
            }
        });
    }


    public class runThread extends Thread {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("Runwa", "run: " + 1);
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    seekBar.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                        }
                    });

                    Log.d("Runwa", "run: " + mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void checkUserPermission(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23){
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},123);
                return;
            }
        }
        loadSongs();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case 123:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    loadSongs();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    checkUserPermission();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        }

    }

    private void loadSongs(){
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC+"!=0";
         cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,null,selection,null,null);
        if(cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                    String SongPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

                    songInfo s = new songInfo(name, artist, SongPath);
                    songs.add(s);


                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();
            songAdapter1 = new songAdapter(songs, getActivity());

        }
    }
}
```

this is my **Adapter**

```
public class songAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<songAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<songInfo> songs;
    Context context;
    OnitemClickListener onitemClickListener;

    public songAdapter(ArrayList<songInfo> songs, Context context) {
        this.songs = songs;
        this.context = context;
    }



    public interface OnitemClickListener{
        void onItemclick(ViewHolder holder, View v, songInfo obj, int position);
    }
    public void setOnitemClickListener(OnitemClickListener onitemClickListener)
    {
        this.onitemClickListener=onitemClickListener;
    }



    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(mView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final songInfo song = songs.get(position);
        holder.songName.setText(songs.get(position).getSongName());
        holder.artistName.setText(songs.get(position).getArtistName());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(onitemClickListener!=null)
                {
                    onitemClickListener.onItemclick(holder,view,song,position);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songs.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView songName,artistName;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            songName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
            artistName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.artistName);

        }


    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static View rootView;
    public static int tabNo;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {


            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tabNo = tab.getPosition();
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tabNo);//setting current selected item over viewpager

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//              View rootView;

            switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
            {
                case 1: {

                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs, container, false);

                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.album, container, false);
                    break;
                }

                case 3: {
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.genres, container, false);
                    break;
                }
                case 4: {
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artist, container, false);
                    break;
                }

            }
            return rootView;


        }

    }
}

recyclerView xml
    <?xm version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar" />
    
        </ScrollView>
    
        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
            android:indeterminate="false" />
    
    
    
    
    </RelativeLayout>

this is cardView

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#f5fffa"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/songName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Shape of you"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/artistName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Ed Sheeran"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>

mainActivity xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.murarilal.musicmania.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No adapter attach,skipping layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057595/no-adapter-attach-skipping-layout)

Comment: don't repeat your question

Comment: no,i told above i have tried almost every answer on stavkoverflow.

Comment: please do check what is the error in above code

Comment: where you are calling `loadSongs()` method @deveshkumawat

Comment: in checkuserpermission() method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't initialize `songAdapter1` again inside `loadSongs()`.

Create a method like this in `songAdapter` class:

```
    public void notifySongAdded(ArrayList<songInfo> songs) {
        this.songs = songs;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And call `songAdapter1.notifySongAdded(songs);` after adding songs inside `loadSongs()`.